# Is it possible to 'force' the app to accept a new model version even if it means overwriting the existing one?

Tags: ios, core-data

Firstly, I'm not 100% clued up on Core Data, but I do what I can. So I've implemented Lightweight Migration for when the app is updated, but recently this has failed, i.e. the app crashes after trying to access the local DB. I currently assume that the reason is because of some mix up with the model versions, but even if not so, I think my question is still valid:

Is there a way, when updating/upgrading an app, to ignore the Core Data migration process and force the app to use the latest model version, even if it deletes the local user data?

My plan is that if the migration fails, force the latest version onto the device. That's a better solution than a crashing app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The migration happens during the `addPersistentStoreWithType` call. So if that fails
and you want to start with a new empty database, just remove the persistent store
file and call `addPersistentStoreWithType` again:

```
_persistentStoreCoordinator = [[NSPersistentStoreCoordinator alloc] initWithManagedObjectModel:model];
if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
    [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:storeURL error:NULL];
    if (![_persistentStoreCoordinator addPersistentStoreWithType:NSSQLiteStoreType configuration:nil URL:storeURL options:options error:&error]) {
        NSLog(@"Unresolved error %@, %@", error, [error userInfo]);
        // Handle fatal error
    }
}
```

This is also useful during *development*, because you don't have to delete the app
each time you change your model.