# CoreData: rm database without migrating

Tags: core-data

I have a CoreData sqlite database that is completely screwed on user's devices in production.

I would like to `destroyPersistentStore` in case if the db can't be migrated, but the funny thing is that this call under the hood seems to use sqlite truncation and requires the database to be well migrated by the time of calling it. So it doesn't work for me.

Deleting sqlite file from the file system is the tried and tested solution, but this question is not about solving this problem by any means necessary.

Is there an API in CoreData to nuke the database without requiring it to be even valid?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19900348/is-it-possible-to-force-the-app-to-accept-a-new-model-version-even-if-it-means doesn't work? It tries indeed a migration, but it's unclear if you want to delete anyway or just in some cases when the migration fails.

Comment: yeah, this is a valid solution, but my question is about doing it without directly manipulating the file system